# How to throw AccessDenied Exception in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, cancan

I have the following bit of haml code

```
 %tr
            %td= account['name']
            %td= account['id']
            %td= account['description']
            -if account['edit']
              %td= link_to shorten(account['data']), data_path(account['id'])
              -if can? :modify
                %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_data_path(id: account['id'])
              -else
                %td None
            -else 
              %td None
              -if can? :modify
                %td= link_to 'Create', new_data_path(id: account['id'])
              -else
                %td None
```

and i have the following bit in my application controller

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    render status: 403, template: "/errors/403_forbidden.html.haml"
```

The problem i am facing is that the edit link and create link appear only if the `if can?` conditions are met. I want to make them appear even if the condition is false but throw a Access Denied exception and render the page accordingly on clicking the links .

Comment: i think that the condition should be as "- if can? :edit, Data". u forgot to specify the model name.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the can block and try out. If user is not authorised in Your ability file to do this, he will get the error. Also ensure that AccessDenied block is in ApplicationController or any other parent controller that Your target controller inherits from.